# Vector as a linear combination of other Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a set of vectors and in $\mathbb R^3$ in a $3\times 6$ matrix already in row-reduced echelon form. I had to express one of $v_1(1, 0, 0), v_3(0,1,0)$, and $v_6(3,-2, 0)$ as a linear combination of the others. I calculated it as $(3, -2, 0) = a(1, 0, 0) + b (0, 1, 0) $

I obtained $a = 3$ and $b = -2.$ And expressed it as $v_6 = 3v_1 - 2v_3.$ I was incorrect and the answer key said it should have been $v_6 = -3v_1 + 2v_3.$ What step am I missing?

Comment: They gave us the matrix already in row reduced echelon form but not the original \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&5&0&3\\0&0&1&0&0&-2\\0&0&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

You can check calculations to verify your answer.

You get $v_6=3v_1-2v_3$ which is perfectly fine as $3(1,0,0)-2(0,1,0)=(3,-2,0)=v_6$

But $-3v_1+2v_3=-v_6 \neq v_6.$